# Notice: unserialize() for symfony2 ( connection user )

Tags: php, sql, symfony, bundle

Here I have this error when I click on the submit button to get connected.

`Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 9 bytes in /var/www/Blog/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/ArrayType.php line 48`

Gist: https://gist.github.com/AnthonyPavaux/5104546

Comment: You have a file name and a line number. Why don't you start debugging from there?

Comment: Line 48 ArrayType.php is the function `return serialize ($ value);`
But it belongs to the library in Symfony2 Doctrine so I must not touch

Comment: what are you setting as `$roles` before you try to persist the entity?

Answer (score 6):

You can replace strings inside this array fields.

I got this problem too for my 'ROLES' column.

Replacing strings inside by :

> a:0:{}

for user role, and

> {i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";}

for admin role corrected my problem.

Comment: Another roles: a:1:{i:0;s:16:"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN";}, a:1:{i:0;s:11:"ROLE_AUTEUR";}, etc...

Comment: Thank you, it was the single qoutes that caused the error. Changing to doubles solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this same error because I had recently changed one of my entity fields to an array. This error was popping up on the page that would list all entities, but because I never updated the database values for this field (they were still integers, when php was expecting the serialized array format), it would die with this error.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error but when installing fos_user, in my case I needed a json format value like "a:{}" but in my field I got for some reason "(Excluded)" so when trying to figure out what happened I checked a db backup and noticed that what I need was insert a "a:{}" value and everything worked smooth.